# Failed method: org.freedesktop.portal.Settings.Read NotFound

Tags: google-chrome, freeze

The first time I detected this problem was when I opened pgadmin4. It displayed a window, but the screen was invisible. Then I noticed the same issue with Google Chrome. Additionally, the screen behaves poorly, only painting where the mouse pointer passes until I close the application.

When running pgadmin4 in the terminal, I received the following output:

```
[12155:12155:0809/170635.434625:ERROR:chrome_browser_cloud_management_controller.cc(162)] Cloud management controller initialization aborted as CBCM is not enabled.
[12155:12155:0809/170635.509296:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(590)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.portal.Settings.Read: object_path= /org/freedesktop/portal/desktop: org.freedesktop.portal.Error.NotFound: Requested setting not found
```

Running Chrome:

```
[12275:12275:0809/170727.000361:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(590)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.portal.Settings.Read: object_path= /org/freedesktop/portal/desktop: org.freedesktop.portal.Error.NotFound: Requested setting not found
```

I tried reinstalling xdg-desktop-portal and xdg-desktop-portal-gtk, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this issue was solved by using proprietary drivers instead of the recommended one :/

Comment: same problem here with the latest google chrome 117.0.5938.132,I am using 2 pc with both kubuntu 20.04, one with nvidia gpu, another with gpu inside intel cpu. google chrome do not work on both pc, the error message is ```[53178:53178:1004/095132.731296:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(576)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.portal.Settings.Read: object_path= /org/freedesktop/portal/desktop: org.freedesktop.portal.Error.NotFound: Requested setting not found``` I searched on google many times, readed 50+ threads but no solution found.
Can you tell more detail about **using proprietary drivers**?

Comment: Can you please elaborate in your answer: (1) "proprietary drivers", which ones? (2) How did you find the driver as cause ?